# Can EF4.1 Code First express simultaneous 1-1 and 1-many to same table?

Tags: entity-framework, entity, poco, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

The high level problem: I'd like speed lookup on table I have a 1-many relationship to.

I've got a large log-like table with a foreign key to an employee table. I'd like to have a relation from the employee table to the most recent log entry (for that employee) as well as the regular Collection of many log entries. I could use only the one to many and just query on last timestamp and employee Id on the logfile, but I'd prefer a direct pointer.

Is it possible to do something like this with Annotations?

```
public class TagEntry
{
    public int TagEntryId { get; set; }

    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public DateTime LogTime { get; set; }
    public string log { get; set; }

    public virtual Tag tag { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{

    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public TagEntry CurrentTagEntry { get; set; }
    public int TagEntryId { get; set; }

    public string someTagData { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TagEntry> TagEntries { get; set; }
}
```

One solution would just be to store a integer currentTagEntryId, but ideally I'd like to reference the Log with tag.CurrentTagEntry.log type notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatelly this is not possible through mapping. Your `CurrentTagEntry` reprents one-to-one relation between `Tag` and `TagEntry` but in the same time you have one-to-many relation between `Tag` and `TagEntry`. One-to-one mapping demands that both entities share primary key => to be able to map one-to-one relations TagEntry's PK must be FK to `Tag`. This will obviously break one-to-many relation.

You must do this as helper function instead of mapping.

For example this can be used as helper linq query:

```
var lastLog = (from te in context.TagEntries
               where te.TagId == id
               orderby te.LogTime descending
               select te).FirstOrDefault();
```

Or this as helper loading:

```
var entry = context.Entry<Tag>(tag);
if (!entry.Collection(t => t.TagEntries).IsLoaded)
{
    // Selective eager loading
    entry.Collection(t => t.TagEntries)
         .Query()
         .OrderByDescending(te => te.LogTime)
         .Take(1)
         .Load();
}

var tag = tag.TagEntries.FirstOrDefault();
```